# Why is the custom info window adapter only showing the last item of the array?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I get the data I want to display, with a custom info window from a Json file. I am looping through the Json file and creating the markers. Now I want to fill the custom info window adapter with the Json array data. Somehow I am only getting the last item of my array. The result is that now every marker has the same title.

in the line title.setText(companyName); It gives me the last company name in the array and I don't understand why.

private void jsonParse() {

```
    final String url = "url";
    Log.d(TAG, "jsonParse: is now in jsonParse ");

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: is before try");
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("companies");
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: is now in try");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                         JSONObject address =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: is now in for loop");
                             companyName = address.getString("name");
                            Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(address.getString("latitude"));
                            Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(address.getString("longitude"));


                            JSONArray jsonArray1 = address.getJSONArray("jobs");
                            for(int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++){
                                JSONObject jobs = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                                     jobTitle = jobs.getString("job_title");
                                }
                                jobCounter++;
                            }


                            mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "getInfoWindow: is in getInfoWindow");
                                    return null;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
                                    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.customInfo_Title);
                                    TextView snippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.customInfo_Snippet);

                                    Log.d(TAG, "getInfoContents: is in getInfoContents");


                                    title.setText(companyName);
                                    snippet.setText("this is the" + "\n\n" + "info about me");

                                    return v;
                                }
                            });


                            //adds markers
                            LatLng companies = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(companies)
                                    /*.title(companyName)
                                    .snippet("amount: " + jobCounter)*/);
                            jobCounter = 0;





                            /*todo now I have to get the job titles... form json with for loop and their links this I set into snippet
                              adding clickable text  or on click marker to go to webseite inform about how to use mobile browser...
                              >a< is a solution for clickable text in javascript...
                            */

                            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MarkerInfo.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: is after for loop");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: caught catch");
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting info window adapter in the loop?

Comment: I am new at android dev, but I thought I need to put it in the for loop, so I can get all the different "companyName" in it. Where should I put it to show for each marker a different company name?